# Is it okay to, to Install kernel 5.1.x in debian 9 stretch?

Tags: debian

I am using debian 9 stretch. It comes with linux kernel 4.9.

One of my quad core cpu's cores were remain at peaks, and much of my hardware is not working like my touchpad and speakers.

So I installed kernel 4.19, from blackport.

It has improved.
However problem still exist, but so far better than now (now only freezing for 3 to 5 seconds).

But kernel 5.1.5 is not in the repository.

My questions are:

Will installing kernel 5.1.x give improved results?

How can I get notified about new kernel version?

Or can I install from other sources? and after installing, will I get update for kernel?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I am struggling to read this: There are many grammar errors, and aberrations. Not all user of this site are native English speakers. Please correct, if you want people to read it.

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is with the kernel?

Comment: Because, many of my hardware was not working like my touchpad, speakers plus all with this my cpu usage was high too,always one of my processor was almost 100%.

Comment: I have made some improvements to the question, it is now readable (e.g. no longer containing “It gave a good result, it was back freezing most of times , But problem still exist but …”. Please proofread to check that it says what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

> Installing kernel 5.1.x will given any improved results?

Most certainly not. I believe you are in a mistake here.

Having 20-40% CPU usage when idle is completely normal, there are background system processes that are working and are consuming processor cycles. They use that much because the system is mostly idle and no other processes are using the CPU, so they have the freedom to use as much as they need. This is expected behaviour and it's completely fine. What you need to look out for is the **system load**, as long as that is low - everything is fine with your system. You can't expect CPU usage to drop to less than 20%, just because you are not doing anything on the machine.

> So do I wait? How can I get notified about kernel new version?
>   Or I install from outside? after installing, I will get update for kernel?

I suggest you wait, because a kernel from outside is incredibly tricky, unstable and risky - it could very well break your system.

And as long as you update your system regularly - you will receive the new update whenever it comes. Debian cannot notify you automatically about this, you should just run `apt-get update` daily to see if there are any new updates (you can list upgradable packages with `apt list --upgradable`).

Debian systems are made to be **extremely** stable, so we, Debian users, receive updates later than most other distros, however, it is for the best if you want a stable system.

Comment: Thank for sharing your views and taking out time answer my question, that was helpful. Actually while listening music, many times I have problem like trackes goes and back and forth in time interval of 2 sec. It's noticeable a lot. After installing such a stable OS, i m having this minor issue feel strange, ad lots of time its freeze for 3 to 5 sec with cursor too. This is first time of mine using debian, due to stability I have installed but facing these minor issues. Can you suggest me what can I do ?